# Set a header by Content-Type

Tags: apache, header, apache2, content-type

I have used this before;

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 2 weeks"
  // Lots omitted here
</IfModule>
```

And this;

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|JPG)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600"
  </filesMatch>
  // Lots omitted here
</IfModule>
```

I can set the expires on by content-type and I can set any header I wish by file extension.

But neither of these seem to let you set any header you want by content-type.

I want to set the cache-control header based on the content-type of the response - note that this is not the same as the file extension. I have "friendly URLs" so there is no file extension to be captured by `filesMatch` so there is no file extension but the content-type is `text/html`.

How can I set the cache-control header for specific content-types?

Comment: Does the Cache-Control header exist in your response?

Comment: "How can I set the cache-control header for specific content-types?" - This is what the `ExpiresByType` directive does (well, specifically, it sets the `max-age` directive of the `Cache-Control` header, as well as the `Expires` header for backward compatibility). However, if you wanted to set "any header" or specific directives in the `Cache-Control` header then you would need a different method.

Answer (score 9):

In 2.4, you can append `expr=` to the Header directive instead of `env=`. For example:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600" "expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} == 'text/html'"
```

In the default (non-early) mode, `mod_headers` runs as an output filter – so the content type is already set and available by the expression parser.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am on version 2.2

Comment: The [Apache 2.4 expression docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) say that `CONTENT_TYPE` is not available during `<If>`. I have found this to be inaccurate, it is available during `<If>` (2.4.52).

Comment: @Jeff I don't think this can be true aside from something like  a contrived case where you have "header set early Content-Type".

https://pastebin.com/3kP2syS3 demonstrates the current behavior that matches the manual

On a conceptual level: <If> expressions are evaluated before all of the following happen, so there should be no meaningful content-type available to query
1. before request is mapped to disk 
2. before the"type_checker" hook is called to allow modules to guess content types
3. before the "handler" (CGI, proxy, etc) has run which will set the content-type during processing

Answer (score -1):

I guess you will need to append or set the Cache-Control header first. Please try the snippet below and do not forget the "no-transform" param.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 2 weeks"
  // Lots omitted here

  //This is the magic
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header append Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't this helps at all either. `Header append Cache-Control "public, no-transform"` does not take into account the content-type?

Comment: Note that before Apache 2.2.12 it was not possible to set the `Cache-Control` header with the `Header` directive.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make the cache content-type you can enter it in this way:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive on

ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 15 days"

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This sets the `ExpiresByType` header. This is not what I need. I need to be able to set the `Cache-Control` By the content-type.

Comment: @JakeN "This sets the ExpiresByType header." - I guess you meant `Expires` header, `ExpiresByType` is the mod_expires _directive_. But even on Apache 2.0, this should also set the `Cache-Control` header (by the mime-type / `Content-Type`). AFAIK you'd have to go back to Apache 1.3 for this to _only_ set the `Expires` header.